# Javascript + Chartkick multiple data sets or grouping

Tags: javascript, grouping, chartkick

I hava a dataset like this:

```
CompanyName CustomAreaCode  SalesMonth01    SalesMonth02    SalesMonth03
Company1    AA1A            20              30              40
Company1    AA1B            23              32              43
Company2    AA1A            23              42              45
Company2    AA1B            87              65              98
```

I am using `Javascript` ant `Charkick`. I want to make chart which would have `sales` on `Y axis`, and there would be `SalesMonth` on the `X axis`, but grouped by `CustomAreaCode`. Final chart should look something like the one in example (sorry for my painting skills):
[image]

My code to create chart:

```
new Chartkick.ColumnChart(chartName, chartDataItem, { 
"library": { "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF", "hAxis": { "title" : xtitle },
"vAxis": { "title" : ytitle, "viewWindow": { "min": chartMin3, "max": chartMax3 } } },
"discrete": true,
"colors": ["#82aef5", "#484c57", "#9987f6", "#FFE57B", "#FFCF7B", "#FFB07B"]});
```

Data JSON i have at the moment (don't know where to put Area code):

```
[
    {
        "name":"Company1",
        "data":
            {
                "2015-01":20,
                "2015-02":30,
                "2015-03":40
            }
    },
    {
        "name":"Company2",
        "data":
            {
                "2015-01":23,
                "2015-02":32,
                "2015-03":43
            }
    },
    {
        "name":"Company1",
        "data":
            {
                "2015-01":23,
                "2015-02":42,
                "2015-03":45
            }
    },
    {
        "name":"Company2",
        "data":
            {
                "2015-01":87,
                "2015-02":65,
                "2015-03":98
            }
    }
]
```

Comment: So do you want the code written by this weekend or next?

Comment: I'm pretty sure writing code is easier than drawing this graph. Also don't use `code tags` for `emphasizing`.